Credit score hit when applying to preapproved card that wasn't preapproved
I go to the BoA app, and they say that I'm preapproved for a few of their credit cards. I apply for one of them and I'm rejected.
Today I get an email that my credit score went down 10 points.
Is there anything I can do? The only reason I applied for it was because the app was showing it to me as a preapproved card.

Why does that matter?  It is a short term fluctuation that is of no consequence.

I tagged this united-states as credit scores work differently around the world. If I've guessed your location wrong please edit or comment.

Unfortunately, this is normal. 'Pre-approved' means absolutely nothing really, read the fine print.


Is there anything I can do?

Wait for the inquiry to get old enough so it doesn't impact your score.  The most likely cause is a new credit inquiry due to the application ("preapproved" doesn't really mean that you are already approved). If you have no other "negative" activity then your score should increase naturally.
There's really nothing to "fix" - you did apply for a credit card and that should reflect on your credit history.  You can be upset that they made you think there wouldn't be a credit inquiry because they marketed it as "preapproved", but I doubt there's anything you or they can do about it.
I would also note that the drop in your score should not impact your day to day life - it only matters when you apply for new debt. No one is monitoring your score to change your monthly bills or anything else.

Well . . . some jobs might require a healthy credit score, and a landlord might well want one.  Having said that, 10 points is unlikely to matter in either case.

The thing to do is just wait. Your score will go back up.
About the “preapproved” card.
Preapprovals do not guarantee approval. They take a look at your credit score, and nothing else, and they notify you in some way asking you to apply for the card.
When you apply, they actually check your credit and make a decision. This will hit your credit. It is called a “hard pull”.
A quick note: “Soft pulls” do not hit your credit.
Never trust companies who want you to apply for a credit card unless you want the card enough that you aren’t concerned about it hitting your credit. Honestly, if you are that worried about a few points on your credit score, I would highly advise you avoid any and all credit cards and loans.


The only reason I applied for it was because the app was showing it to
me as a preapproved card.

The marketing department did its job. They got you to apply. Because you already had the app, that meant you were already a customer, and their goal was to get another financial connection to you.
Unfortunately to be pre-approved means that you met some of their criteria, but until you actually applied they didn't have all of the information they needed to make a decision.

Today I get an email that my credit score went down 10 points.

Assuming that these events are connected, it isn't surprising there is a drop in your score. There can be other things that make a score fluctuate such as having a higher than normal balance on your existing cards, but I would assume it was the new credit application.

Is there anything I can do?

Wait. Eventually the score will go back up. Also review your rejection notice to see exactly why it was rejected. It is possible that in the future you can meet their criteria.
While 10 points isn't a disaster, it can cause a problem if that drop puts you below a threshold that an employer or landlord would care about.
The lesson is don't believe the marketing department. Also getting rejected can cause a drop in score.
